# Setting initValues in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to set initial display value for the users in redux-form Fields.It has to be dynamic , the values are given by this.props.editName which is passed down by a parent component.I know how to set static value to initValues in redux form but I am getting error while setting initValues from this.props 
What works:

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'editTeamForm',
    initialValues: {
        name: 'India'
    },
    validate
  })(EditTeam)
```

what doesnt work:

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'editTeamForm',
    initialValues: {
        name: this.props.editName
    },
    validate
  })(EditTeam)
```

The Error shown in browser:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass initialValues to your EditForm component wherever you render it.

```
<EditTeam initialValues={{ name: editName }} />
```

EDIT: If you need to get your initialValue from redux you can handle this in your `mapStateToProps` function too. As long as the resulting prop is called initialValues it should work!